# How do you make an application run as soon as you open your pc

Tags: windows, kiosk-mode

I'm doing this personal project that involves an application that kind off extends the process of login into your pc.

Basically it just has a few more password type things and its just to make login process more fun.

All I really need to know is how do you make it so as soon as you login with the main windows login system this application can run and as an added bonus if it could be unclosable so you cant just close it and use the computer.

Comment: Google kiosk mode. That should get the ball rolling for you.

Comment: You are looking for a [service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/services). Also see: [What if two programs did this?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050607-00/?p=35413)